# Lenovo A6000 isn't turning on

Tags: troubleshooting, lenovo-a6000-plus

My Lenovo A6000 is not working when I try booting it. It shows me a blank screen. When I press the power button multiple times, it keeps blinking showing me a white screen then black afterwards. I tried to remove the battery, and waited for a couple of minutes and tried it again. I tried charging it, but it keeps blinking.

Answer (score 1):

Try to press the Power button for 30 seconds. Also try to start in fastboot mode (usually volume up or volume down + power button) while being plugged to a computer.

Also, maybe worth a try but will delete user data:

1. Switch off the device
2. Press & hold Power and Volume up until screen changes to recovery mode.
3. Select Recovery mode.
4. Using Volume up & down for navigation. Select Wipe Data/Factory Reset and enter it through Power key.
5. Now, Select Yes (delete all user data)